# Exporting Accounts and Contacts

Tags: data-export

I have all Salesforce Account ids' in a CSV file. Now I would like to export the accounts and contacts from Salesforce org based on this. I am unable to figure out on how to achieve this. Any insights would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If these are all account id's, why do you need to export based on that file? Can't you just export all accounts and all contacts?

Comment: I just separated all the account ids' of the accounts with activities(tasks and events) from the entire accounts. Now I need to insert these records in another salesforce instance. Now I just need to extract account information based on these ids'. Is there any way?

Comment: How many, 5, 500, or 5,000?

Comment: 6400 account ids to be uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, based on your technical skills and on the amount of records you are processing.

However, to keep the chances of errors as low as possible, I'd advise the following:

1. create a checkbox field on Account (named e.g. 'toExport')
2. based on the list with id's you have, fill the new checkbox field. This can be done with dataloader. Add another column to the csv where you update the checkbox to 'true'
3. create reports for accounts and for contacts that filter on the checkbox field. For contacts you will need to use the 'accounts with contacts' report type so you have the checkbox field in your report filter options.
4. you can clean up the checkbox field after completion if you want

Other alternatives might require coding or copy-pasting of lots of data which don't seem appropriate in this case.